# User Class - Combining Functions

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have recently started reading up on classes and functions to allow me to create a user system for an online game community I am part of.  I currently have three tables to provide me with user data: ***divisions***, ***ranks***, and ***users***.

The ***users*** table looks like:

```
user_id | user_name | char_name | email | password | rank_id
```

The ***ranks*** table looks like:

```
rank_id | rank_name | div_id
```

The ***divisions*** table looks like:

```
div_id | div_name
```

There will be about 100 ranks, with each rank being in a specific division.  For example, ranks 1-5 are division 1, ranks 6-10 are divisions 2, and so on.

***OLD CODES ARE BELOW***

I have created a ***User*** class with functions to grab the data I need, but I feel like I am doing it wrong, since there are a lot of SELECT statements being used, and I'm calling all three functions on a test page to get the data.

My ***User*** class is as follows:

```
require_once('dbcon.php');
class User {
    public static function all_users() {
        global $conn;
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    public static function by_id($userid=0) {
        global $conn;
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :userid');
        $records->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    public static function get_rank($userid=0) {
        global $conn;
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :userid');
        $records->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rankid = $results['rank_id'];
        $records2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE rank_id=:rankid');
        $records2->bindParam(':rankid', $rankid);
        $records2->execute();
        $results2 = $records2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results2['rank_name'];
    }
    public static function get_div($userid=0) {
        global $conn;
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :userid');
        $records->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rankid = $results['rank_id'];
        $records2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE rank_id=:rankid');
        $records2->bindParam(':rankid', $rankid);
        $records2->execute();
        $results2 = $records2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $divid = $results2['div_id'];
        $records3 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM divisions WHERE div_id = :divid');
        $records3->bindParam(':divid', $divid);
        $records3->execute();
        $results3 = $records3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results3['div_name'];
    }
}
```

My test page to get people's data is:

```
require_once('inc/dbcon.php');
require_once('inc/user.php');
echo "<strong>ALL USERS</strong><br><br>";
$users = User::all_users();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $rank = User::get_rank($user['user_id']);
    $div = User::get_div($user['user_id']);
    echo "User Name: " . $user['user_name'] . ".<br>";
    echo "Character Name: " . $user['char_name'] . ".<br>";
    echo "Rank: " . $rank . ".<br>";
    echo "Division: " . $div . ".<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
echo "<strong>USER 1</strong><br><br>";
$singleuser = User::by_id(1);
$rank = User::get_rank($singleuser['user_id']);
$div = User::get_div($singleuser['user_id']);
echo "User Name: " . $singleuser['user_name'] . ".<br>";
echo "Character Name: " . $singleuser['char_name'] . ".<br>";
echo "Rank: " . $rank . ".<br>";
echo "Division: " . $div . ".<br>";
```

How can I go about improving this?

Is there a way to do get_rank and get_div in a JOIN statement, perhaps, within the all_users and by_id, which would prevent the multiple statements?

***OLD CODES ARE ABOVE***

***EDIT 1***

I looked into why using globals are bad, so I will work on setting up the function to use a constructor instead, based on what I read.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I might be able to condense it further by maybe joining get_rank and get_div to all_users and by_id?

***EDIT 2***

After looking into why globals are bad to use, I have changed a few things around.  I managed to combine all of the SELECT statements into a proper INNER JOIN.

*CONFIG.PHP*

```
include 'db.class.php';
include 'user.class.php';

define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "agency");
$database = new Database();
$user = new User();
```

*DB.CLASS.PHP*

```
class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;
    private $dbh, $error, $stmt;
    public function __construct(){
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

*USER.CLASS.PHP*

```
class User extends Database {
    public function test3($id){
        $this->query('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN ranks ON users.rank_id = ranks.rank_id INNER JOIN divisions ON ranks.div_id=divisions.div_id WHERE users.user_id=:id');
        $this->bind(':id', $id);
        $rows = $this->resultset();
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

I have tested the above in a test file.

*TEST.PHP*

```
include 'assets/config/config.php';
foreach($user->test3(1) as $row){
    echo $row['user_name'] . " has a rank of: " . $row['rank_name'] . ".  This rank has an ID of: " . $row['rank_id'] . ".";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['user_name'] . " is in division: " . $row['div_name'] . ".  This division has an ID of: " . $row['div_id'] . ".";
}
```

***NEW QUESTIONS***

1. With the SELECT statements now combined, is the setup better than before?
2. Is the table setup optimized?  Is there a way to maybe combine it into two tables?

***TABLES AND SAMPLE DATA***

```
CREATE TABLE `divisions` (
  `div_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `div_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `divisions` (`div_id`, `div_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Div 1 Name'),
(2, 'Div 2 Name'),
(3, 'Div 3 Name');

CREATE TABLE `ranks` (
  `rank_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `div_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `ranks` (`rank_id`, `rank_name`, `div_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Rank 1 Div 1', 1),
(2, 'Rank 2 Div 1', 1),
(3, 'Rank 3 Div 1', 1),
(4, 'Rank 4 Div 1', 1),
(5, 'Rank 5 Div 1', 1),
(6, 'Rank 6 Div 2', 2),
(7, 'Rank 7 Div 2', 2),
(8, 'Rank 8 Div 2', 2),
(9, 'Rank 9 Div 2', 2),
(10, 'Rank 10 Div 2', 2),
(11, 'Rank 11 Div 3', 3),
(12, 'Rank 12 Div 3', 3);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `char_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rank_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `char_name`, `email`, `password`, `rank_id`) VALUES
(1, 'UserA', 'CharA', 'EmailA', 'PassA', 2),
(2, 'UserB', 'CharB', 'EmailB', 'PassB', 10);

ALTER TABLE `divisions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`div_id`);

ALTER TABLE `ranks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`rank_id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

As requested by one of the comments, here are the tables and some sample data.  Again, everything is working as intended.  I am just trying to get questions 1 and 2 answered, to see if this setup is correct.  This is limited test data.  There are about 100 ranks, and will be about 100 users.

Depending on the users rank id, they will have the appropriate rank name, and be in the appropriate division.

Comment: Hands off from _globals_...

Comment: Thank you, I guess?  I will look into why globals shouldn't be used.  Other than that... any other help in how to maybe condense it/make it better?

Comment: I added the SQL dump, using test data, to an edit, so you can see it as requested.  I mainly just need the new questions 1 and 2 answered, to make sure this system makes sense and is structured correctly, as the original codes were way off.

Comment: The DDL is ok, there's no much that mysql can do (data normalization seems correct). But your code still a mess. A class changing its state using constants is so bad as global variables. Look at Dependency Inversion Principle. A database has a state (connected, disconnected, etc..) . A class that uses a connection has a state too. Static methods are supposed to be stateless (usually stateless, there're a few exceptions).

Comment: You might have better luck over on codereview.stackexchange.com